# numpy overflow shape 256 configuration

Tags: python, numpy, configuration

This piece of code represents my problem:

```
import numpy as np

def test(n):
    X = np.random.normal(0, 1, [n,n])
    print(n, "->", np.linalg.norm(np.dot(X,X)-np.dot(X,X)))

test(256) # This should print "256 -> 0.0"
test(257) # This should print "257 -> 0.0"
```

An output of this program on my computer is:

```
256 -> 0.0
257 -> 213.90038618585083
```

This output is representative for n<=256 and n>256.
On another computer this works fine.

Here the output of np.show_config().

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
    language = c
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_clapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['lapack', 'lapack', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
```

Does anyone have an idea how this overflow error occurs?
(I'm running an arch linux.)

Followup:
This is the configuration of the machine it works on:

```
blas_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Does the other machine (on which it works fine) have BLAS support enabled? I just tried on my machine, and there it works fine, too (I am using Intel MKL as the BLAS backend for NumPy).

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I got frustrated and went with the boot force method and reinstalled all relevant software.